# How do I add a Google account (add person) using the command line?

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, automation, chromium

For an automatization process inside a virtual machine, I need to add/login into a Google account on Chrome or Chromium using the command line only.

Comment: What OS is the VM?

Comment: @Twisty I intend to use debian or ubuntu. But I could go with a RedHat derivate too.